# How to query for documents where array has a field more than n number of times in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection `world` with documents in the following format:

```
{
  _id : ObjectId("4e8ae86d08101908e1000001"),
  country : [
      {
          state: "Newyork",
          type: 1
      },
      {
          state: "California",
          type: 1
      },
      {
          state: "Texas",
          type: 2
      }
  ]
}
```

We can easily get documents that have four or more states in the arrary:

```
db.world.find({'country.4': {$exists: true} })
```

But how can I get the documents where a country array having four or more states of `type: 1`?

Also, I want to avoid `$where` operator in the query.

**Edit 1**

Answer by *Blakes Seven* seems right to me but when I try to do the reverse i.e; get the documents with ***less*** than n fields then I get faulty results:

Here is the query:

```
db.world.aggregate([
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": {
                "$lte": [
                    { "$size": { "$setDifference": [
                        { "$map": {
                            "input": "$country",
                            "as": "el",
                            "in": {
                                "$cond": {
                                    "if": { "$eq": [ "$$el.type", 769 ] },
                                    "then": "$$el",
                                    "else": false
                                }
                            }
                        }},
                        [false]
                    ]}},
                    4
                ]
            },
            "then": "$$KEEP",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }}
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottom line is you need to filter out non matches and "count" the occurrences of matches in order to determine if the document meets your conditions. This can be done with the [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator on a filtered array as part of a logical test with [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/).

The suggestion of [`$setIsSubset`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) made elsewhere cannot work since a "set" essentially cancels out any duplicate items. This means that any matching will reduce down to:

```js
"$setIsSubset": [[1,0],[1]]
```

Which is of course a `false` condition. This is because most cases where there are array members that do not match ( thus producing `0` ) and where each "set" is effectively reduced to it's "unique" members. And even when "all" members were matched then the result reduces to this:

```js
"$setIsSubset": [[1],[1]]
```

Which while a positive match, this makes absolutely no assertion that the required "number" of matches is actually met.

So as long as the array members themselves are in fact "unique", then you can rather take this approach to filter and count the matches:

```js
db.world.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "country.3": { "$exists": true } }},
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": {
                "$gte": [
                    { "$size": { "$setDifference": [
                        { "$map": {
                            "input": "$country",
                            "as": "el",
                            "in": {
                                "$cond": {
                                    "if": { "$eq": [ "$$el.type", 1 ] },
                                    "then": "$$el",
                                    "else": false
                                }
                            }
                        }},
                        [false]
                    ]}},
                    4
                ]
            },
            "then": "$$KEEP",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }}
])
```

So returning the whole element for the "set" comparison of [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) to filter out any `false` values that were returned. The resulting array without the matches is then tested for `$size` to see if the requisite matches was met, and documents are discarded via `$$PRUNE` where they do not.

Of course [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) here does the job of processing each element to either return the original element whole or alternately `false` in it's place where the condition is not met.

If there was in fact duplicate information for say "California" within the array that was important to count, then future MongoDB releases will have `$filter` which both simplifies the process a little and most importantly does not remove duplicates when reducing to a "set":

```js
db.world.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "country.3": { "$exists": true } }},
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": {
                "$gte": [
                    { "$size": { "$filter": {
                        "input": "$country",
                        "as": "el",
                        "cond": {
                            "$eq": [ "$$el.type", 1 ]
                        }
                    }}},
                    4
                ]
            },
            "then": "$$KEEP",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }}
])
```

But of course until that release is available, you need a more traditional approach using `$unwind` and `$match` to filter the array while keeping duplicates and then obtain the "count" via `$group` first:

```js
db.world.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "country.3": { "$exists": true } }},
    { "$project": { "country": 1, "countryCopy": "$country" } },
    { "$unwind": "$country" },
    { "$match": { "country.type": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "country": { "$first": "$countryCopy" }
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$match": { "count": { "$gte": 4 } }}
])
```

But hopefully you don't have duplicates in the array so it wouldn't matter.

Also important to use that initial [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to immediately filter out arrays without the required number of elements to possibly match ( array index is `n-1` ) by testing that the minimum index at least exists and discarding documents from being processed with less than `4` elements in total in this case.

This is the [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) test which is useful here. That cuts down trying to match documents in later processing that cannot possibly meet the required match count due to not having enough elements to start with.